# Add new data to Graphics2D panel in a Java Swing application

Tags: java, swing, graphics2d

I am writing a Java Swing application for data processing.
one of the functions I need to add is to visualize the data in a graphical way.
For this I want to use the Graphics2D class.

I have a GUI created, integrated my program and also a panel that draws the graphics using the Graphics2D class.

But my problem is that I can't figure out how to call the drawLine method after selecting and loading a file from the GUI

Below is short code example, showing my issue.
It just contains a basic GUI with 2 panels and a menu with load option to explain my problem:

In de MyFrame.java file, I put a comment at line 87 to show exactly where I am stuck.

The appl is based on 3 files:
main: here it creates an instance of MyFrame of the GUI
Myframe: creates the GUI and further process of data
MyPanel: makes a Jpanel of the Graphics2D with a base blue rectangle frame as start view.

If Anyone could give me a hint on how to call this drawLine method from outside the MyFrame() constructor...

I still don't fully understand the whole point on how to interact between classes...

here is a picture of what the GUI looks:

[image]

Thank you for helping me on this

```java
public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MyFrame();                      
    }
}
```

2. MyFrame.java:

```java
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    JTextComponent tc;
    String fileName;
    
    MyFrame() {
     this.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
     this.setLayout(null);
     this.setBounds(0,0,464,312);
     
     tc = new JTextPane();
     tc.setBounds(0,520,450,50);
     tc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,50));
     
     JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tc);
     
     JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
     JMenu fm = new JMenu("File");
     JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load file");
       loadItem.addActionListener(e -> {tc.setText("loading"+"\n");
                                        SDprocess();});
       fm.add(loadItem);
       mb.add(fm);
       
     MyPanel p1 = new MyPanel();
       p1.setBounds(0,0,450,200);
       p1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,200));
       
     JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
       p2.setBounds(0,200,450,50);
       p2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450,50));
       p2.add(sp);
       
     this.setJMenuBar(mb);  
     this.add(p1);
     this.add(p2);
     this.setResizable(false);
     this.setVisible(true); 
    }
    
    
    public void SDprocess() {
    
        File fr = null;
    
        JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        int result = fc.showOpenDialog(this);
       if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            
            fr = fc.getSelectedFile();
            fileName=fr.getName();                  
            System.out.println(fileName);
        }   
        try {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fr);
                tc.setText(fileName +" loading\n");
            while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = sc.nextLine();
                
            // ...
            // rest of code to get the x and y data for drawing
            // lines using  drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2) method. 
            //
            // at this point I need to call this drawLine method but how ???
            // i just don't know how to call this method from this point and how to 
            // and update the graphics panel p1 after adding the data....
            }
        sc.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }   
}
```

3. MyPanel.java:

```java
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    Graphics2D g2D;
    
    MyPanel() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (450,200));
    }
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        
        g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
        g2D.drawLine(5, 5, 445,5);
        g2D.drawLine(445, 5, 445,195);
        g2D.drawLine(445, 195, 5,195);
        g2D.drawLine(5, 195, 5,5);          
    }   
}
```

Comment: *"I uploaded a simplified application.."* [Edit] to add a [mre] (here). All relevant code should be included as (code formatted) text right here. *"with load option"* Hard code some data. `MyFrame` is a terribly non-descriptive name for the class. How about `DataVisualizer` or `DataVisualizerWindow`? Longer, but a whole lot more useful.

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right. But I created a short example to show my issue.

Comment: Shouldn't paintComponent be overridden instead of paint?

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer: yes, and the super for the overridden method should also be called inside the painting override.

Comment: Indeed... But it does not solve my problem on how to call the drawLine method outside the constructor.

Comment: The GUI works and the action event also, i can load the file, display its name and content etc. But I don;t know how to feed the x,y data to a method that receives the x and y int values and executes a drawLine method. This call is done after the inital GUI creation and i am runing a method inside the MyFrame class .

Comment: The current MyPlane class does create a Graphics plane with the 4 blue outer lines and it is shown on the Panel (p1) as set in the Myframe class, so that is working, even with overriding Paint instead of PaintComponent .....  But then .... how to add new lines to it...

Comment: I am sorry, but I am lost, I think I just don't fully get the usage of class interaction.

Comment: *But I don;t know how to feed the x,y data to a method* - you just create a method to add the data to the model of your drawing panel. Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example of this approach. The simply example allows you to dynamically add any number of objects to draw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Netbeans section.

Here's the revised GUI before "reading the file".

[image]

Here's the revised GUI after "reading the file".

[image]

I created an application model to hold the line segments.  This model is passed to the drawing `JPanel` so that the line segments can be drawn in the `paintComponent` method of the drawing `JPanel`.

I cleaned up your GUI.  I used [Swing layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to create the GUI.  I separated the creation of the `JPanels` from the creation of the `JFrame` so the code is easier for people to read and understand.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class ExampleDrawingGUI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new ExampleDrawingGUI().new MyFrame());
    }

    public class MyFrame extends JFrame {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private ExampleDrawingModel model;
        
        JTextComponent tc;
        
        MyPanel p1;

        public MyFrame() {
            super("My Frame");
            this.model = new ExampleDrawingModel();
            this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            this.setJMenuBar(createMenuBar());
            
            p1 = new MyPanel(model);
            this.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            this.add(createTextPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
            
            this.pack();
            this.setLocationByPlatform(true);
//          this.setResizable(false);
            this.setVisible(true);
        }
        
        private JMenuBar createMenuBar() {
            JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
            JMenu fm = new JMenu("File");
            JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load file");
            loadItem.addActionListener(e -> {
                tc.setText("loading" + "\n");
                model.readFile();
                p1.repaint();
            });
            fm.add(loadItem);
            mb.add(fm);
            
            return mb;
        }
        
        private JPanel createTextPanel() {
            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            
            tc = new JTextPane();
            tc.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 50));
            JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(tc);
            panel.add(sp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            
            return panel;
        }
        
        public void repaint() {
            p1.repaint();
        }

    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private ExampleDrawingModel model;

        public MyPanel(ExampleDrawingModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 200));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);

            Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
            paintBorder(g2D);
            
            for (LineSegment line : model.getLines()) {
                Point startPoint = line.getStartPoint();
                Point endPoint = line.getEndPoint();
                g2D.drawLine(startPoint.x, startPoint.y, endPoint.x, endPoint.y);
            }
        }

        private void paintBorder(Graphics2D g2D) {
            int margin = 5;
            int x1 = margin;
            int x2 = getWidth() - margin;
            int y1 = margin;
            int y2 = getHeight() - margin;
            
            g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
            g2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
            g2D.drawLine(x1, y1, x1, y2);
            g2D.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y1);
            g2D.drawLine(x2, y1, x2, y2);
            g2D.drawLine(x1, y2, x2, y2);
        }

    }
    
    public class ExampleDrawingModel {
        
        private List<LineSegment> lines;
        
        public ExampleDrawingModel() {
            this.lines = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        
        public void readFile() {
            this.lines.clear();
            // Here's where you'd read a file and create a list of lines.
            lines.add(new LineSegment(new Point(100, 100), new Point(100, 150)));
        }

        public List<LineSegment> getLines() {
            return lines;
        }
        
    }
    
    public class LineSegment {
        
        private final Point startPoint, endPoint;

        public LineSegment(Point startPoint, Point endPoint) {
            this.startPoint = startPoint;
            this.endPoint = endPoint;
        }

        public Point getStartPoint() {
            return startPoint;
        }

        public Point getEndPoint() {
            return endPoint;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Nice answer!  .... 1+ :D

Comment: Hi Gilbert, thanks a lot ! for this comprehensive answer.

Comment: Hi Gilbert, thanks a lot ! for this comprehensive answer. I need to study on it because I do not yet fully grasp all the basics of Java, but I am making a program that does Gcode transposing to enable me to create a special Gcode file that is not possible to create with standard slicing software.. 
My example was messy like also Hovercraft mentioned. In my actual GUI I already used preferred size and pack() to get a good layout but in this example... well it looks just perfect !. Still a lot to learn on my side :). Thanks again for your help !

Comment: Gilbert, if I well understood, your also use threads for the  Myframe() to  have it update the GUI.

Comment: My routine that loads the data, is actually part of a large class, that does data manipulation, creates and intermediate file and with a stringbuilder creating the final data to write to the transposed gcode file. Can I implement all of this within the readFile()  method? or will the GUI freeze up. A typical time to process a file and create the output file  can be up to about 1 minute (in case of large data, this means over 10 Mio lines of data lines to process (i don't need to visualize all , just about 5000 points , the rest is processed  without visualization)

Comment: @xpsion: You didn't say your input file was that large,  Yes, the GUI would freeze while you read your file.  Use a Swing Timer or a [worker thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) to read your file.

Comment: ok, thanks, that will enable a progress bar or something visual to update indeed.

Answer (score 3):

First off, some problems with your code:

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

    //....

    MyFrame() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);  // !! Good God, no don't do this!
        this.setBounds(0, 0, 464, 312); // and don't do this
```

Avoid null layouts and setBounds like the plague as this makes for very inflexible GUI's that while they might look good on one platform look terrible on most other platforms or screen resolutions and that are very difficult to update and maintain. Instead you will want to study and learn the layout managers and then nest JPanels, each using its own layout manager to create pleasing and complex GUI's that look good on all OS's.

Also, don't forget to call `pack()` on your JFrame *after* adding components and before setting visible, in order for the layout managers to do their things.

And then:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    // ...

    Graphics2D g2D; //!! -- no, don't do this
```

If you create a Graphics or Graphics2D field, you are tempted to use it outside of a painting method, and this is a recipe for disaster since any Graphics obtained from a component is short lived and doing this risks creating a brittle graphic or throwing a NullPointerException

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        
        g2D = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
        g2D.drawLine(5, 5, 445,5);
        g2D.drawLine(445, 5, 445,195);
        g2D.drawLine(445, 195, 5,195);
        g2D.drawLine(5, 195, 5,5);          
    }
```

Don't override paint but rather paintComponent since this is less risky (paint has greater responsibilities that you don't want to mess with) and smoother animations if needed since paintComponent uses double buffering by default.

Also, you almost *always* should call the super's painting method in your own override, and so instead do:

```
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // first call the super's method:
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();
```

---

Now as for your actual problem, creating images and drawing after the GUI has been rendered, probably the easiest way to do this is to create a BufferedImage and draw with it in your GUI. You can do this easily by calling Graphics method `drawImage(...)`. And you can pass a BufferedImage into your drawing JPanel any time it is needed. So for instance, your code could look something like...

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {          
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("GUI");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            
            MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
            MyMenu myMenu = new MyMenu();
            myMenu.setMyPanel(mainPanel.getMyPanel());
            myMenu.setMainPanel(mainPanel);
            
            frame.add(mainPanel);
            frame.setJMenuBar(myMenu);
            frame.pack();
            frame.setResizable(false);
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);  
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }
}
```

```
class MainPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(4, 40);
    private MyPanel myPanel = new MyPanel();
    
    public MainPanel() {
        textArea.setFocusable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        add(myPanel);
        add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }
    
    public MyPanel getMyPanel() {
        return myPanel;
    }

    public void appendTextAreaText(String text) {
        textArea.append(text);
    }
    
    public void setBuffImg(BufferedImage bImage) {
        myPanel.setBuffImg(bImage);
    }
}
```

```
class MyMenu extends JMenuBar {
    private MainPanel mainPanel;
    private MyPanel myPanel;
    
    public MyMenu() {
        JMenu fm = new JMenu("File");
        JMenuItem loadItem = new JMenuItem("Load file");
        loadItem.addActionListener(e -> {
            // Emulate reading file here in a background thread
            
            if (myPanel != null) {
                int width = MyPanel.MY_WIDTH;
                int height = MyPanel.MY_HEIGHT;
                BufferedImage bImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

                Graphics2D g2 = bImg.createGraphics();
                
                // draw with g2 here using data from file

                // emulating this:
                g2.setColor(Color.RED);
                
                float strokeWidth = (float) (2 + 6 * Math.random());
                g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeWidth));
                g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
                
                int x2 = (int) (MyPanel.MY_WIDTH * (1 + Math.random()) / 2);
                int y2 = (int) (MyPanel.MY_HEIGHT * (1 + Math.random()) / 2);
                g2.drawLine(5, 5, x2, y2);
                
                g2.dispose();
                
                myPanel.setBuffImg(bImg);
                
                if (mainPanel != null) {
                    mainPanel.appendTextAreaText("adding image \n");
                }
                
            }
        });
        fm.add(loadItem);
        add(fm);        
    }
    
    public void setMyPanel(MyPanel myPanel) {
        this.myPanel = myPanel;
    }
    
    public void setMainPanel(MainPanel mainPanel) {
        this.mainPanel = mainPanel;
    }
    
    
}
```

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int GAP = 5;
    public static final int MY_WIDTH = 450;
    public static final int MY_HEIGHT = 200;
    private BufferedImage bImg = null;

    // Graphics2D g2D; //!! -- no, never do this!!

    MyPanel() {
        // this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 200));
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    
    // better to override getPreferredSize
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(MY_WIDTH + 2 * GAP, MY_HEIGHT + 2 * GAP);
    }
    
    public void setBuffImg(BufferedImage bImg) {
        this.bImg = bImg;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // first call the super's method:
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (bImg != null) {
            g.drawImage(bImg, GAP, GAP, null);
        }

        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
        g2D.setPaint(Color.blue);
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(GAP, GAP, getWidth() - 2 * GAP, getHeight() - 2 * GAP);
        g2D.draw(rect);
    }

    // Don't override paint but rather paintComponent
    // public void paint (Graphics g) {

}
```

Comment: Hi Hovercraft, Thank you for this very clear explanation and remarks.
I still have a lot to learn about using Java.... 
With this example (I need to study..) and the one of Gilbert, my question has been more then answered!